# XPages view control link manipulation

Tags: xpages

I have a view control and at least one column has the option "Display as link" set. The link is generated manually. What I want to achieve is to add a url parameter which is added to a view column link. The usual link would like this

"http://host/path/file.nsf/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?databaseName=server!!path/file.nsf&documentId=03871DD0B47F88D4C12576AB00623137&action=editDocument"

What I would like to have is:

"http://host/path/file.nsf/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?databaseName=server!!path/file.nsf&documentId=03871DD0B47F88D4C12576AB00623137&action=editDocument?param1=value1&param2=value2&etc..."

There must be a (presumably easy) way to achieve this - unfortunately I don't know how... 
Any help or hint is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance. 
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the below steps:
1. go to All Properties of view Column which displays column values as link.
2. Compute the PageUrl with the below Code.

```
    var col:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumn = getComponent("viewColumn1");
col.getDocumentUrl()+"&param1=value1"
```