# Xpages ViewPanel: Overwrite Expand link

Tags: view, xpages

I have an Xpage that display a categorized view within a viewpanel.

I am unable to customize the 'link' or the 'onclick event' for the categories. Domino overwrites these always with the expand function, which I do not want.

I tried:

```
<xp:viewColumn columnName="productnumber"
    id="viewColumn2" styleClass="ViewcatFilter"
    collapsedImage="/spacer.jpg" expandedImage="/spacer.jpg">
    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="" id="viewColumnHeader2"
        sortable="false">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    <xp:link id="link2">
        <xp:this.value>#</xp:this.value>
        <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:myVar.getColumnValue("productnumber")}]]></xp:this.text>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"
            id="eventHandler3">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.searchQuery = myVar.getColumnValue("productnumber")}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:link>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

[XPages view control link manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741366/xpages-view-control-link-manipulation)

I assume you can manipulate the link of categorized columns the same way than "normal" columns.